# Wait for images appended using ajax have loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.post("service.php", { GetStartpageImages : true },function(data) {

    $.each(data,function(i, value){

        var path = "uploads/thumb_" + value.Filename;

        $('.startpage-images').append(
        '<div class="imagewrapper clearfix">' +
            '<a class="imagelink" href="?p=photo&id=' + value.ID + '">' +
                '<img src="'+ path +'"/></a>' +
                '<div class="imageinfo alpha70">'+ value.UploadTimestamp +'</div>' +
            '</a>' +
        '</div>');

    });
});
```

How can i show them once they are loaded? `$(window).load..` didnt work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$.post("service.php", { GetStartpageImages : true },function(data) {

    $.each(data,function(i, value){

        var path = "uploads/thumb_" + value.Filename;

        $('.startpage-images').append('<div class="imagewrapper clearfix">' +
        '<a class="imagelink" href="?p=photo&id=' + value.ID + '">' +
            '<img src="'+ path +'"/></a>' +
            '<div class="imageinfo alpha70">'+ value.UploadTimestamp +'</div>' +
        '</a>' +
        '</div>');


        function imgLoadCallback(){
            $('.imagewrapper').show();
        }

        var img = new Image();
        img.addEventListener('load', imgLoadCallback, false);
        img.src = path;


    });
});
```

The above code assumes that in your css you have `.imagewrapper {display:none}`. Once the image has been fully loaded, `imgLoadCallback()` will be called. Even if the user has the image in their cache, it will still be called (immediately, in that case).

Comment: All I can say is that my code works. I used this kind of thing as recently as this morning. It appears that you're loading multiple images, not just one. I'll nee you to post more code to help you out.

Comment: Yep, all accept this since the problem isnt your code - it was the html posted above that was the load event to fail. This might be useful for someone else :) Thnaks for helping though!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
$.each(data,function(i, value){
  var path = "uploads/thumb_" + value.Filename;
  $('.startpage-images').append(
    '<div class="imagewrapper clearfix">' +
        '<a class="imagelink" href="?p=photo&id=' + value.ID + '">' +
        '<img data-src="'+ path +'"/></a>' +
            '<div class="imageinfo alpha70">'+ value.UploadTimestamp +'</div>' +
            '</a>' +
        '</div>');
});

$('.startpage-images img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
});
```

so I would set the attr `data-src` and at the end set it to the `src`

Comment: Thanks, but im afraid the result remains the same. Link: http://83.254.112.18/fotosida/. Clear cache and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
'<div class="imageinfo alpha70">'+ value.UploadTimestamp +'</div>'
```

Without this the .load method worked. No clue why, might be some jquery bug.